# Easy question about codimension of points of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let's say $X$ and $Y$ are varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose there is  birational morphism $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$. In particular this is dominant. For example's sake let's say this is the blowup of a point $p$ on $X$. Then some exceptional divisor lies above $p$ with generic point $\eta$ whose local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\eta}$ has dimension $1$ since the point has codimension $1$. But then this maps to the point $p$ which has codimension $2$ in $X$ so the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{p}$ has dimension $2$. Then we obtain a morphism of local rings,
$$
\mathcal{O}_{p} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\eta}.
$$
This is injective since the morphism of varieties is dominant. But this means we have an inclusion from a dimension $2$ ring into a dimension $1$ ring. How is this possible?

I am sure I am just being totally stupid here and missing something incredibly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for inclusions to preserve Krull dimension. For instance, consider the inclusion of a domain in to its field of fractions: the former can have any dimension you want, but the latter always has dimension zero because it is a field.

Your stated example corresponds to the map on local rings $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}\to k[x,t]_{(t)}$ given by sending $x\mapsto x$ and $y\mapsto tx$. This is a perfectly good local map of local rings.